# How to map XML to JAVA model in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm developing an android app and I have some data in XML format from HttpResponce. I want to map that data into Java model. is there any common way that takes Java object and XML data and converts the XML data into Java model. Because I need to write the parsing code every time when I got the XML for different web service.

The following code used for Java, is there any code for Android?

```
File file = new File("question.xml");  
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Question.class);  

Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
Question que= (Question) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  

System.out.println(que.getId()+" "+que.getQuestionname());  
System.out.println("Answers:");  
List<Answer> list=que.getAnswers();  
for(Answer ans:list)  
   System.out.println(ans.getId()+" "+ans.getAnswername()+"  "+ans.getPostedby());
```

Comment: tyr to used JSON parser...

Comment: Json parser is used to convert json data into java model but i have xml data

Comment: convert XML to JSON data..

Answer (score 2):

You may use for [gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml) for XML deserialization. It's well documented and  have some example which you can go through.

Usage:

```
public static class SimpleModel {
  private String name;
  private String description;

  public String getName() { return name; }
  public String getDescription() { return description; }
}


public void simpleTest() {

  XmlParserCreator parserCreator = new XmlParserCreator() {
    @Override
    public XmlPullParser createParser() {
      try {
        return XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  };

  GsonXml gsonXml = new GsonXmlBuilder()
     .setXmlParserCreator(parserCreator)
     .create();

  String xml = "<model><name>my name</name><description>my description</description></model>";
  SimpleModel model = gsonXml.fromXml(xml, SimpleModel.class);

  assertEquals("my name", model.getName());
  assertEquals("my description", model.getDescription());
}
```

Use @SerializedName annotation to handle tag attributes and text nodes.

To illustrate, this XML:

```
<person dob="01.01.1973" gender="male">
  <name>John</name>
  Likes traveling.
  </person>
```

can be mapped to a POJO:

```
public class Person {

  @SerializedName("@dob")
  private String dob;

  @SerializedName("@gender")
  private String gender;

  private String name;

  @SerializedName("$")
  private String description;

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[Simple Xml Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php)".

Comment: this should be a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice Tutorial for Mapping `XML` to `POJO (Plain Old Java Object)`

http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-or-standard-java-mapping-your-xml-onto-pojos-easily-and-vice-versa/

Please go through the demonstration provided in the above link and your problem will be solved.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I m getting an exception com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

Comment: Please share your code and error logs, so that e may be able to help you solving it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use JSON parser instead of XML.It is easy to code both in Java and Javascript.

Comment: but i have data in xml formate in httpresponce. i have not jsone data